# Bootstrap tab - active class not working on page loading

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code is below. Notice the tab 'one' is active. But the problem is when i open the page, the tab really shows active, BUT the tab content does not show ; it only shows when i click on the tab manually. How to fix this ?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#one">One</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Two</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="one">
    <p>Tab one content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="two">
    <p>Tab two content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add class `active` also on the selected tab content

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#one">One</a></li>
  <li class="nav"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#two">Two</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

  <!-- Show this tab by adding `active` class -->
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="one">
    <p>Tab one content</p>
  </div>

  <!-- I removed `in` class here so it will have a fade in effect when showed -->
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="two">
    <p>Tab two content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Have a look at this:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79zjyd6L/1/)

Comment: For those who it still doesn't work, see @jafaritaqi's answer where you remove the "fade" class on the tab

Answer (score 26):

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="one"> <p>Tab one content</p> </div>
```

Change this to

```
<div class="tab-pane active in" id="one"> <p>Tab one content</p> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The accepted answer doesn't work at all, my code was like this at the beginning and removing the "fade" did the trick

Answer (score 17):

It seems that having a combination of "fade" with the "active" class on the tab content seems to be conflicting on my particular usage of the tab panels.  It still didn't load the content on the initial page load.

Once I removed "fade" then things seemed to work.

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="sales" role="tabpanel">
```

Comment: this was my issue in 2022 bs5

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but using navpills.

None of the other solutions worked for me. Finally I solved it using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    // somehow first navpill will not look active on page load (although it is...)
    $('.navpill.active').trigger('click');
});
```

I guess it would work the same for navtabs, only use $('.nav.active') to locate the correct element.

Answer (score 2):

The only way that worked for me was with JS.
Put on the first item:

```
<li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link active" ....
```

And this code:

```
$(".nav-tabs li a").click(function(){
  $(".nav-tabs li a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!! I'd been trying to fix it since few days. HTML was correct and I couldn't find what was going wrong. The problem with my code was, it was adding the "active" class to the anchor tag <a> instead of <li>. I just tweaked your code by adding "parent()" and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you try getting the values from the backend, there is some possibility that it can still not work. Try adding `show` right next to `active`:

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="one">
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the "active" class, in the beginning, does work.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li><a class="active nav-item nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a> </li>
<li> <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a> </li>
<li> <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer doesn't seem to differ very much from the accepted answer...