# Bootstrap 4 Tabs Fade Yielding Extra Space on N+1 Tabs

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following tabs set up in my Rails 5.2 app with Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="classic-tabs mx-2 mb-5">

  <ul class="nav" id="myClassicTabShadow" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link  waves-light active show" id="tab-all" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-all" role="tab" aria-controls="area-all" aria-selected="true">All</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link  waves-light" id="tab-general" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-general" role="tab" aria-controls="area-general" aria-selected="true">General</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link waves-light" id="tab-seo" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-seo" role="tab" aria-controls="area-seo" aria-selected="false">SEO</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link waves-light" id="tab-sm" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-sm" role="tab" aria-controls="area-sm" aria-selected="false">Social Media</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link waves-light" id="tab-templates" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-templates" role="tab" aria-controls="area-templates" aria-selected="false">Templates</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-sm card" id="myClassicTabContentShadow">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="area-all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-all">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @resources } %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="area-general" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-general">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @general } %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="area-seo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-seo">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @seo } %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="area-sm" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-sm">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @sm } %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="area-templates" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-templates">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @templates } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- classic tabs -->
```

The tabs look fine and switch content right, but on all tabs but the first, there is blank space above the proper content where the previous tabs' content was.  (So it's right on tab 1, tab 2 shows a blank space the height of tab 1's content then the content for tab 2, tab 3 shows blank space for the content from 1 and 2 above the actual tab 3 content, etc.)

I've looked at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594068/bootstrap-4-default-tab-pane-active-fade-in-not-working) and tried to debug in a fiddle to ensure the problem isn't elsewhere in my app, but the issue is consistent.  I have also tried it with just a single word as the tab content (instead of the rendered partial) and the problem persists so I know it isn't an error within the rendered partial.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**UPDATE**

I put just the rendered code in a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2mph8sr/) and it appears to work okay, but when it's rendered on the page (visible [here](https://scarytechforbloggers.com/resources)) the issue still appears.  Here's the entire page, if that makes a difference:

```
<main class="container-fluid px-5">

  <% if current_user && current_user.admin %>
    <section class="text-right pt-2">
      <%= link_to 'Add a New Resource', new_resource_path, class: "btn btn-blue btn-sm" %>
    </section>
  <% end %>

  <heading class="text-center my-5">
    <h1>Scary Tech Resources</h1>
  </heading>



  <!-- Classic tabs -->
<div class="classic-tabs mx-2 mb-5">

  <ul class="nav" id="myClassicTabShadow" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link  waves-light active show" id="tab-all" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-all" role="tab" aria-controls="area-all" aria-selected="true">All</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link  waves-light" id="tab-general" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-general" role="tab" aria-controls="area-general" aria-selected="true">General</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link waves-light" id="tab-seo" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-seo" role="tab" aria-controls="area-seo" aria-selected="false">SEO</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link waves-light" id="tab-sm" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-sm" role="tab" aria-controls="area-sm" aria-selected="false">Social Media</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link waves-light" id="tab-templates" data-toggle="tab" href="#area-templates" role="tab" aria-controls="area-templates" aria-selected="false">Templates</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-sm card" id="myClassicTabContentShadow">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="area-all" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-all">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @resources } %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="area-general" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-general">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @general } %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="area-seo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-seo">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @seo } %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="area-sm" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-sm">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @sm } %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="area-templates" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-templates">
      <%= render partial: "resources/tab_interior", locals: { resources: @templates } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- classic tabs -->

<!-- Classic tabs -->





</main>




<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card-text').matchHeight();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Could you share the rendered markup? A [mcve] would be ideal. I don't care what builds it. I only care about the final markup and the applied CSS. Which is precisely what browsers care about, too.

Comment: @tao I added the rendered text in a JS fiddle as well as the surrounding page for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#myClassicTabContentShadow .fade:not(.show) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
#myClassicTabContentShadow .fade.show {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

...fixes it.

What does the job is `position: absolute`. The rest is minor styling to fix the animation.

Basically, the `.card` rules conflict with with the `.tab-sm` rules. Most likely, placing them on two different elements (`.tab-sm > .card`) would also work.

Comment: Argh!  I should have thought of absolute positioning days ago!  Thank you so much.  This got it working perfectly.