# AngularJS Boostrap tabs does not show anything for active tab when it is shown in dialog

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I have many tabs in my showDialog, when I set `tab_2` as active, the content shows nothing which is strange.

```
 <div class="portlet-body">
    <div class="tabbable-blue" id="my_tabDialog" style="margin:0px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-lg">
            <li id="li_tab_1">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#" data-target="#tab_1">
                    MyTab1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="li_tab_2" class="active">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#" data-target="#tab_2">
                    MyTab2
                </a>
            </li>
           
          
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab_1" class="tab-pane fade meter-tabs-height">   
                <div ng-include="'mytab1.html'"></div>         
            </div>
            <div id="tab_2" class="tab-pane fade in meter-tabs-height" active>

                <div ng-include="'mytab2.html'"></div>    
               
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

When I firstly come into the dialog, the dialog shows `MyTab2` with no content at all.
However, when I click `MyTab1` and then reclick `MyTab2`, the content appears.

How does this happen and how could I handle this problem?Thank you.

Comment: can you create a plnkr please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap tab - active class not working on page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078987/bootstrap-tab-active-class-not-working-on-page-loading)

Comment: @Ryan, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44728614/4315380), you will have to remove `fade` I guess. Instead of `fade in` try `active` class

Comment: @tanmay Yes,thank you very much. It turns out that I need to put `active` as `class` insted of an attribute in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a mistake in my code, just add `class="active"` could resolve it.

Replace

```
<div id="tab_2" class="tab-pane fade in meter-tabs-height" active>
    <div ng-include="'mytab2.html'"></div>                
</div>
```

with

```
<div id="tab_2" class="tab-pane fade in meter-tabs-height active">
    <div ng-include="'mytab2.html'"></div>                
</div>
```